# Remove objects from a List based on their path

Tags: java

I have two lists:

```
private final List<EventTeaserModel> events = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<EventTeaserModel> premiumEventList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The use case for my method `removePremiumEventsFromEvents()` is to remove premiumEventList `objects` from the events List (remove objects with the same path).

Here is what I tried and it works. Is there a better way to do it in Java?

```
private void removePremiumEventsFromEvents() {
            for (EventTeaserModel premiumEvent: premiumEventList) {
                List<EventTeaserModel> findDuplicatedEvent = events.stream()
                        .filter(event -> event.getResource().getPath().equals(premiumEvent.getResource().getPath()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                events.removeAll(findDuplicatedEvent);
            }
        }
```

Thanks to @Chaosfire @Thomas @marstran
I was able to improve my method:

```
private void removePremiumEventsFromEvents() {
        final Set<String> paths = premiumEventList.stream()
                .map(EventTeaserModel::getResource)
                .map(Resource::getPath)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        List<EventTeaserModel> duplicatedEvents = events.stream()
                .filter(event -> paths.contains(event.getResource().getPath()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        events.removeAll(duplicatedEvents);
    }
```

Comment: This might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but in general this would be O(m * n) complexity since you're iterating over the other list for each element of the first. Building a set first and accessing that would reduce that to O(m * log(n)). But why not store the events in a set in the first place? Can the lists contain duplicates? Does order matter? (Note: `LinkedHashSet` gives you set properties with insertion order iteration). - If the events are unique but considered duplicate based on their path then using a map path->event instead of a set might help.

Comment: Looks like it could be simplified by using [removeIf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) with the same predicate you are currently using to filter.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Thease are two distinct lists of events. I am trying to remove event objects with the same path.

Comment: Thanks @Chaosfire I was able to simplify according to your comment:
`for (EventTeaserModel premiumEvent : premiumEventList) {
            events.removeIf(event -> event.getResource().getPath().equals(premiumEvent.getResource().getPath()));
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is kinda similar to yours conceptually, but it looks a bit cleaner.
You can first find all paths in `premiumEventList`, then use `removeIf` on `events` for each of the paths. Like this:

```java
private void removePremiumEventsFromEvents() {
    premiumEventList.stream()
        .map(EventTeaserModel::getResource)
        .map(Resource::getPath)
        .forEach(path -> events.removeIf(event -> 
            event.getResource().getPath().equals(path)));
}
```

Personally however, I like to keep my lists unmodifiable/immutable. So I would instead create a new `events` list with the elements filtered. Like this:

```java
private void removePremiumEventsFromEvents() {
    final Set<String> paths = premiumEventList.stream()
        .map(EventTeaserModel::getResource)
        .map(Resource::getPath)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // Or preferrably, return the new list.
    events = events.stream()
        .filter(event -> !paths.contains(event.getResource().getPath()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Both approaches have different properties which you might want to point out: 1) is basically 2 nested loops (the stream +  the removeIf() for each element), 2) uses an intermediate set of paths which makes it more efficient for a reasonably large number of events. - Btw, the filter condition should be negated, shouldn't it? -> `.filter(event -> !paths.contains(event.getResource().getPath()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do `events.removeAll(premiumEventList);` `removeAll()` is a method of interface `List`. However you will need to override `hashcode()` and `equals()` for your `EventTeaserModel` class so it identifies equal Objects in the way that you want them to be compared.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on my comment: if both lists can be large a complexity of O(n * m) could become problematic. Thus, using an intermediate set might help:

```
private void removePremiumEventsFromEvents(List<EventTeaserModel> events, List<EventTeaserModel> premiumEvents) {           
  //Build the map of premium event paths - O(n)
  Set<String> pePaths = premiumEvents.stream()
          .map(event -> event.getResource().getPath())
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());

  //this is an in-place removal and thus we can't use a stream here
  //if you'd want to create a copy of the list you could use:
  // events.stream().filter(e -> !pePaths.contains(e.getResource().getPath())).toList()
  Iterator itr = events.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
    //Iterate over events - O(m)
    EventTeaserModel event = itr.next();

    //check if path is premium - O(log(n))
    if( pePaths.contains(event.getResource().getPath()) {
      itr.remove();
    }
  }

  //Overall complexity: O(n + m * log(n)) -> O(m * log(n))
}
```

Comment: Great answer @Thomas and commented code. Thanks so much. I really appreciate your complexity comments.